# How to disable TinyMCE from auto formatting when insert content from source code - Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, tinymce

I created a TinyMCE together with a textarea(for entering the source code) as picture below. The TinyMCE and textarea is bind with ng-model(angularjs). Whenever I enter a word in source code area, it is formatted directly with `<p>` tag. How to prevent this happen? 
[image]

It work fine in Google Chrome and IE as below, but not in Firefox.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the tinymce setting `forced_root_blocks` to `false`.

> If you set this option to false it will never produce P tags on enter or automatically it will instead produce BR elements and Shift+Enter will produce a P.

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:forced_root_block

**Edit:**
By default tinymce removes newlines from the source code. To disable this funcitnality try the setting:

```
remove_linebreaks : false
```

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:remove_linebreaks

Comment: Hi @Mario A, I tried your method, the "<p>" doesn't appear anymore when I type the word. However, when I hit enter button, the cursor cannot move down to second line. It keeps staying on first line. Any idea?

Comment: strange. does the sourcecode produce a "<br>" when you hit enter?

Comment: yes, it produce <br> when i hit enter if I type the word in tinymce area. However, if I enter the codes in source code area and hit enter, it will not produce <br>, instead, it produce a space and still stay on the first line. I think the reason might because of direct binding between the tinymce textarea and source code textarea. Do you have any idea on how to prevent the source code textarea from directly influenced by the formatting of tinymce?

Comment: I guess this has to do with tinymce removing linebreaks from the source code. I made an update of my answer.